# Simple data update with talend

Tags: sql-update, talend

I have a job in talend which migrates some data from one database to another... At the end of data migration, I should update the date of last extraction in the source database with SYSDATE so it could be used as a criteria for the next extraction. The SQL query would be something like :
    `UPDATE MIGR_FOLLOWUP SET LAST_EXTR = SYSDATE WHERE SYSTEM = 'TARGET3'`

I'd like to do that update in talend, and I guess it should be a component triggered by OnSubjobOK, but I just can't seem to understand how to do this in a simple manner... The only way I could possibly think of is using both tOracleInput and tOracleOutput components, in order to first extract the wanted row and then update it, but it really doesn't sound like a good manner to do this...

Can anyone point me out on how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: if am correct then you can achieve this by tOracleRow component, and yes you should do it after after extraction job completion, use onSubJobOk link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run arbitrary SQL by using the database row components such as tOracleRow.

If you linked this with an on subjob ok link from your main migration then once your main migration completes successfully it would update the `LAST_EXTR` field with the current time.

Alternatively you could update this using a tOracleOutput component but you would need to have Talend define the date-time stamp using something like `Talend.getCurrentDate` in a tMap or tFixedFlowInput.